# remu instruction expanded to include break instruction - ALWAYS stops program

Tags: mips, qtspim

I'm learning MIPS by using QtSpim. In the code below, a remu pseudo-instruction is expanded to include a break instruction. I imagine that the break is to catch a divide by zero, but in this case, it stops the code from functioning regardless:

```
            .text
            .globl main

main:       li          $s0, 113        # $s0 holds n, the number to test.
            div         $s1, $s0, 2     # $s1 is n / 2, the limit for the loop.
            li          $s2, 2          # $s2 is the counter starting at 2.

while:      beq         $s2, $s1, set
            nop
            remu        $s3, $s0, $s2
            beq         $s3, $0, unset
            nop
            addiu       $s2, $s2, 1
            j           while
            nop

unset:      li          $s7, 0          # $s7 is unset if n isn't prime.
            j           end
            nop

set:        li          $s7, 1          # $s7 is set because n is prime.

end:
```

The remu instruction is expanded to:

```
[00400040] 16400001  bne $18, $0, 4           ; 10: remu $s3, $s0, $s2 
[00400044] 0000000d  break                    
[00400048] 0212001b  divu $16, $18            
[0040004c] 00009810  mfhi $19
```

The break instruction is always stopping the code, even if $18 ($s2) is non-zero.

Comment: Have you tried disabling delayed branches in the simulator settings?

Comment: @Michael. Yep, that's it. Thanks.